# my icloud is saying that it is not verified. What do I do?

Tags: iphone

I cannot get my icloud to come on.  It is statiing that my icloud is not verified

Answer (score 1):

You should start with logging into iCloud at https://appleid.apple.com from a computer. Once you're sure your Apple ID is OK, then log in to https://icloud.com to check that iCloud is fine.

Lastly, you can go to settings in the iPhone and make sure the time zone and clock are set to within 4 minutes of the real time. Then try signing into iCloud on the device.